# Expression blend 3 wont show Background image

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

i am developing a solution using Expression blend 3 and i have a problem because my background images wont show up in design time, in run time i can see them.

As you can see in the attached picture there is no image in stackpanel.

Is there a solution to this?

[image]

Best regards,
Luka

Comment: My guess would be in how you're declaring the file path. Is the image file in the same directory of the same project? Or should you maybe add a more descriptive file path like ImageSource="/Your.Project.Name;component/Path/To/The/File/03.png"

Answer (score 2):

In blend you should be able to just drop and drag the image onto the workspace from your projects folders, blend then adds the xaml on the fly. If its not in your project folder you should create a images folder and "add existing item" then browse to the image.

Comment: I figured out its the problem with Blend 3, i need to rebuild solution then it works, maybe its just Silverlight for embedded project type that couses problems.